# A question about Quasi Hyperbolic metric

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, quasiconformal-maps, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

I am reading Quasicoformally  Homogeneous Domains by F. W. Gehring t And B. P. Palks

Let $D$ be a proper subdomain of $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Define the function $\rho.(x) = \frac{1}{dist(x, \partial D)}.$ For $x,y \in D$, define $$k_D(x,y)= \inf_{\gamma} \int_{\gamma} \rho ds.$$

I know that $$\lim_{y \to \partial D}k_D(x,y) = \infty   \quad \text{ Eq : 2.3}$$.

Suppose $\{x_j\}$ is cauchy in metric $k_D$, I want to show that $\{x_j\}$ is Cauchy in Euclidean metric. Here is the screen shot :
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsvLO.png)

I do not understand

> If $\{x_j\}$ is Cauchy in the metric $k_D$, then $\{x_j\}$ is
> bounded in that metric and, consequently, lies in a compact subset of D in view of
> (2.3). This implies that $\{x_j\}$ is Cauchy in the euclidean metric.

I do not understand compactness mentioned withrespect to which metric. Can someone give more details.

The same question is posted here : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432351/a-question-about-quasi-hyperbolic-m

Comment: Hint: Use the equation (2.3).

Comment: I do not understand how to use eq 2.3, can you possibly write a detailed answer?